# Possible ways to deploy an application to Windows Phone Store using automated tool/process

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, build-automation

**Is it possible to submit a new app or update an existing app to Windows Phone store with any automate process instead of uploading it manually?**

Please suggest the solutions for the same.

I found few automated tools for ios application submission like [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible at the moment and no indication about such feature coming.

Answer (score 0):

There may be such functionality soon.

From https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/31/announcing-new-dev-center-capabilities-to-increase-app-revenue-and-streamline-management/:

> The new Windows Store submission API will be made available in
>   preview, beginning today and rolling out in waves. This new API offers
>   a subset of functionality provided by Dev Center as a REST API and
>   supports these actions for published apps: submitting updates,
>   modifying metadata, and adding/removing in-app products. You can
>   request access to the preview through the “Feedback” tab in Dev Center
>   by selecting “Submission API” in the “Suggestions” tab. Access will be
>   granted in waves, beginning with a small group of developers. Build
>   session: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B839